# Recursively find a directory and rename it in Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Im putting together a simple Shell script to run on a Linux Machine where I would:

1) Look for specific sub-directories within a main directory. These sub-dirs have a very specific naming convention (see below) and they are always 2 -max depth below the main directory.

2) Rename those sub-dirs to PART of its original name.

For example,
The sub directories are named:

```
andrew-11111
andrew-11112
andrew-11113
andrew-11114
```

The path to get to these sub dirs would look something like this:

```
myphotos/sailing/photos/andrew-1111
myphotos/sailing/photos/andrew-1112
myphotos/biking/photos/andrew-1113
myphotos/hiking/photos/andrew-1114
```

Id like take out the 'andrew-' from each of these sub dirs:

```
myphotos/sailing/photos/1111
myphotos/sailing/photos/1112
myphotos/biking/photos/1113
myphotos/hiking/photos/1114
```

Ive gotten as far as "finding" the sub dirs and listing them. I also understand how to copy and rename in command line. But putting it together at my level of shell scripting knowledge has been taking much more time than I can afford. Just a disclaimer, I am more than willing to learn, and have written a handful of shell scripts, but still new to this. Any help or examples are much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with this one-liner:

```
find -type d -name andrew\* -exec sh -c 'mv {} $(dirname {})/$(basename {} | cut -d"-" -f2)' \;
```

Explanation:

- `-type d` find only directories
- `-name andrew\*` self-explaining, you have to escape the `*` though
- `-exec sh -c '...'` execute it in a subshell, so you can do the command substitution (`$(...)`) without problems
- `mv {}` the `{}` holds whatever `find` finds
- `dirname` gives you the path to a directory (try it out with a random path, my english is too bad now to explain better)
- `basename` gives you the last directory of a given path
- `cut -d"-" -f2` use cut to cut off "andrew-". For this set the delimiter to `-` and select the field number 2

Comment: That is a good POSIX compliant solution, but may be a bit heavy on the number of processes spawned per-file renamed.

Comment: Thanks! Ill also tried it this way. My code is much shorter at from this.

Answer (score 5):

Use wildcards to match the files in the nested directories

You can use bash [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) operators to manipulate the filenames.

```
for file in myphotos/*/photos/*; do
    name=${file##*/}    # remove everything up to last /
    dir=${file%/*}      # remove everything from last /
    newname=${name##*-} # remove everything up to last -
    mv "$file" "$dir/$newname"
done
```

If you have the perl-based `rename` command, you can do:

```
rename 's#[^/]*-##' myphotos/*/photos/*
```

Comment: Very interesting. I thought that perl `rename` does not work on folders. Now I know better! Hmm. Not sure I understand _how_ the perl rename works in this case though?
I am accustomed to seeing _three_ slashes (/) whenever I use perl rename.
I cannot recall I have ever seen a left square bracket ([) and a right square bracket (]) being used with perl rename before. I wish I would understand what is going on here ... I assume the `*-##` part is what removes `andrew-` from the deepest sub-directory name?

Comment: You can use any character you want as the delimiter after the `s` command. This allows you to avoid using a character that appears in the pattern or replacement, to minimize the need to escape it. So I used `#` instead of `/`, because `/` appears in pathnames.

Comment: Thanks! That explanation cleared up a LOT of my confusion. 
I tried `rename 's|[^/]*-||' myphotos/*/photos/*` and it works just
as fine. :-)